# How to export stack trace in PhpStorm to text file

Tags: phpstorm

I'm debugging in PhpStorm remotely over SSH. It stopped to my breakpoint and I see the stack trace. The problem is that it's very big.

I would like to copy or export it into a text file to examine closely. In PhpStorm after the PHP script times out the debugging session is closed and I lose the trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK it's not possible in PhpStorm.

The best ticket I could find is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153569 (also has duplicate [IDEA-166237](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-166237)).

Watch that ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

Right now I may only suggest to use PHP's own `debug_print_backtrace()` function or alike (and save its output into a file) or more powerful [PsySH](http://psysh.org/).